# BT dongle - ASUS USB-BT400 not working

Tags: 13.04, usb, bluetooth

I run on one problem. My USB Bluetooth dongle ASUS USB-BT400 is not working.
I'm googling the whole day for some clues, but without success. Could you please help me?

USB device is properly found:

```
lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0b05:17cb ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 17ef:4816 Lenovo
```

But when I try to `hciconfig`, I don't get any output.

I tried it with some old BT dongle, and that worked... But I need to use especially this one because of BT4.0 support.

According to this: http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-bugs/2013-September/053719.html
It uses BCM20702A chipset, which should work under Linux, but maybe it's not properly recognized with this device? (Same issue, which is described in the linked site)

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I e-mailed Asus support to see if the Asus Bluetooth BT-400 was compatible with Ubuntu.  They were no help so I took the chance and ordered one.

I wanted to use this on an older Toshiba Laptop to connect my Motorola S9-HD Headset that is generally connected to my phone for hands free driving.  It works great with 12.10 and 13.10.  I have also tested this on my towers at home that is running 13.10.

I used the bluetooth setup wizard in system settings.  **There is one hitch. I have to turn off the Bluetooth on my phone**.  If my head set is connected to the phone it will NOT connect to the another device.

Unfortunately I don't have another Bluetooth device to this with.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to setup properly this device. The solution can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ssledz/69b7f7b0438e653c08c155e244fdf7d8)

Tested on ubuntu 18.04